# How to use object datasource in RDLC report in webapi2

Tags: rdlc, asp.net-web-api2

In asp.net webapi2 after adding rdlc report When I want to create dataset then I could not find my object data source in wizard(I have found only database wizard.). But in asp.net I have found object datasource. Is there any way to use object datasource in webapi2 rdlc report.